Converting a UTF-8-CSV to UTF-16 (Unicode) in PowerShell
To whom it may concern,
I want to convert my CSV, which is in UTF-8, into UTF-16 using PowerShell. For this task, I wrote the following line of code:
$schuelerCSVUTF8 = Get-Content -Path "C:\tmp\PSProjekt\schueler.csv" | Set-Content -Path "C:\tmp\PSProjekt\lol\schueler.csv" -Encoding Unicode -Force
I see in VS Code that the formatting has correctly changed to UTF-16 LE. But there is a problem.
Some entries get converted correctly:
Before converting, an entry in the CSV looks like this: Z�rcher.
After converting, it looks like this: Zürcher.
But others don't:
Before converting, the entry in the CSV looks like this (already correct): Meriç
After converting, it looks like this (now it's false): MeriÃ§
Does anyone know a solution to that or why that happens?

Get-Content also has a parameter -Encoding and you need to make sure it uses UTF8 when reading the file. However, since this is about a CSV file, why not use cmdlets written especially for that purpose? Import-Csv -Path "C:\tmp\PSProjekt\schueler.csv" -Encoding UTF8 | Export-Csv -Path "C:\tmp\PSProjekt\lol\schueler_Unicode.csv" -Encoding Unicode -NoTypeInformation

Hello Theo, thank you for your response. With your method, VSCode shows that the file is in UFT-16 LE, but nothing has changed. It still says Z�rcher and Meriç.

What are you using to view the files? Changing the encoding format shouldn’t change the decoded content of the file, so if you’re seeing different characters on screen when you open them that might be more to do with the app you’re opening the files with. Have you compared your “before” and “after” files in a hex editor?

No, I haven't. But VSCode shows the same characters as the Active Directory.

What produced your CSV file and how? Was this file originally in a different encoding and converted to UTF-8 afterwards?

Hello Theo, I actually don't know. The file ins't from me.

It seems like the original file is encoded in "ISO-8859-1".

Sounds to me then that the original was badly converted to UTF-8 (the file you are using as input). Perhaps try and convert that original ISO-8859-1 file yourself with Import-Csv -Path "C:\tmp\PSProjekt\schueler_Original.csv" -Encoding Default | Export-Csv -Path "C:\tmp\PSProjekt\lol\schueler_Unicode.csv" -Encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInformation. And yes, I would always prefer UTF-8 over UTF16-LE /// If you are using PowerShell 7.4, change -Encoding Default to -Encoding ansi

powershell 5 is notorious for not recognizing utf8 no bom



If your input file is interpreted as a UTF-8 file and contains both strings such as Z�rcher and Meriç, the implication is that your input file is corrupt:

The presence of �, the Unicode REPLACEMENT CHARACTER, U+FFFD, indicates that a byte (or sequence thereof) in the input file with the high bit set (i.e. a value that is between 0x80 (128) and 0xFF (255), inclusively) did not constitute a valid UTF-8 encoding of a non-ASCII-range character and was therefore replaced with said placeholder character to indicate that fact.


Converting a UTF-8 file that is interpreted as such to UTF-16(LE) involves no loss or transformation of information, so the transformation from Z�rcher to Zürcher and from Meriç to MeriÃ§ you describe cannot happen in that context.

In isolation:

Z�rcher is most likely the result of the mistaken interpretation as UTF-8 of a file that uses a fixed-width, single-byte encoding such as Windows-1252, which is the encoding used as the ANSI code page of the legacy system locale (language for non-Unicode programs) on US-English and Western European editions of Windows, for instance.

Conversely, MeriÃ§ is most likely the result of the mistaken interpretation as Windows-1252 of a file that is actually UTF-8-encoded; each byte in the two-byte UTF-8 sequence that encodes ç (LATIN SMALL LETTER C WITH CEDILLA, U+00E7) in the input file is interpreted as a separate character.



The two PowerShell editions differ fundamentally in which character encodings they use by default:

Windows PowerShell (the legacy, ships-with-Windows, Windows-only edition of PowerShell whose latest and last version is 5.1) uses ANSI encoding by default in its Set-Content and Get-Content cmdlets (and when it reads source code).

That is, Set-Content creates (by definition BOM-less) files with ANSI encoding by default, and Get-Content interprets BOM-less files as ANSI-encoded by default.


PowerShell (Core) 7 (the modern, cross-platform, install-on-demand edition) consistently uses (BOM-less) UTF-8.





The upshot in your case is:

If the input files are truly corrupt (containing a mix of character encodings), fix them first and save them as UTF-8.

Then, read them with -Encoding uf8 to ensure they're being read correctly in case they lack a BOM (not strictly needed in PowerShell 7).


Get-Content -Encoding utf8 -Raw C:\tmp\PSProjekt\schueler.csv | 
  Set-Content -Encoding Unicode -NoNewLine -Force C:\tmp\PSProjekt\lol\schueler.csv 

Note:

If the files are actually ANSI-encoded, omit the Get-Content -Encoding argument in Windows PowerShell and use -Encoding Ansi in PowerShell 7.

If you want to transcode your ANSI files to UTF-8 instead of UTF-16(LE) ("Unicode"), add -Encoding utf8 in Windows PowerShell and -Encoding utf8BOM in PowerShell (Core) 7, which creates UTF-8 files with BOM in both cases and ensures that Windows PowerShell too interprets them correctly.
If, by contrast, you want to create BOM-less UTF-8 files, omit the -Encoding argument in PowerShell (Core) 7; in Windows PowerShell, you'll need a workaround to create such files - see this answer.


-Raw is passed to Get-Content for speed: it reads the input file as a whole into a single, multiline string (which also ensures that the original newline format is retained).

This necessitates passing -NoNewLine to Set-Content, to prevent an extra trailing newline from getting written.


